# Unable to build react app in CI due to path issue

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, create-react-app, concourse

I am trying to build a react app using concourse CI. The app was created using create-react-app, the issue is relating to paths

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Navigation' in
>   '/tmp/build/9d0884a1/app/src'

Tried the following but it did not work

```
"start": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts start",
 +    "build": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts build",
 +    "test": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
 +    "eject": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts eject"
```

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/Navigation' in
>   '/tmp/build/9d0884a1/app/src'

Comment: can you share your folder structure?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Wintermute1/0f4399361454522b159b257066169a4f thanks